Problem with React Form and passing information to backend in Django
I have a view in Django that is responsible for booking a user a training session with a personal trainer. This view wants a full Trainer object, but the react form only passes the trainer ID to Django, despite the PrimaryKeyRelatedField attribute being set in the serializer.
This is error which i got:
Error: Cannot assign "'2'": "TrainingSession.trainer" must be a "Trainer" instance.

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_training_session(request):
    data = request.data

    # Check require information
    if "trainer" not in data or "date" not in data or "duration" not in data:
        return Response(
            {"detail": "Brak wymaganych pól."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )

    try:
        session = TrainingSession.objects.create(
            trainer=data["trainer"],
            client=request.user,
            date=data["date"],
            duration=data["duration"],
        )
        serializer = TrainingSessionSerializer(session, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"detail": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class TrainingSessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trainer = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Trainer.objects.all())
    client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = TrainingSession
        fields = ["id", "trainer", "client", "date", "duration", "status"]

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {Button, Form, FloatingLabel} from "react-bootstrap";
import { bookTrainingSession, listTrainers } from '../actions/serviceActions';

const BookTrainingSessionForm = () => {
    const [trainer, setTrainer] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('');
    const [duration] = useState(60);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const trainerList = useSelector((state) => state.trainerList);
    const { loading: loadingTrainers, error: errorTrainers, trainers } = trainerList;

    const sessionTrainingBook = useSelector((state) => state.sessionTrainingBook);
    const { loading, error, success } = sessionTrainingBook;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listTrainers());
    }, [dispatch]);

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(bookTrainingSession({ trainer, date, duration }));
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div>
                <FloatingLabel>Trener</FloatingLabel>
                {loadingTrainers ? (
                    <p>Loading trainers...</p>
                ) : errorTrainers ? (
                    <div>Error: {errorTrainers}</div>
                ) : (
                    <Form.Select value={trainer} onChange={(e) => setTrainer(e.target.value)} required>
                        <option value="">Wybierz trenera</option>
                        {trainers.map((trainer) => (
                            <option key={trainer.id} value={trainer.id}>
                                {trainer.name}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </Form.Select>
                )}
            </div>
            <div>
                <FloatingLabel>Data</FloatingLabel>
                <input type="datetime-local" value={date} onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)} required />
            </div>
            <Button className='mt-3' type="submit" disabled={loading} variant="primary">
                {loading ? 'Booking...' : 'Book Session'}
            </Button>
            {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
            {success && <div>Session booked successfully!</div>}
        </form>
    );
};

export default BookTrainingSessionForm;



Could you please give me one example of the format for the data that is passed to the argument in the part that creates the TranningSession object in the create_tranning_session function? (data["trainer"], date=data["date"], duration=data["duration"],)

<div className="results-container">
        <h2>Search Results:</h2>
        {results.length > 0 ? (
          <table className="results-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Tier</th>
                <th>Designpattern</th>
                <th>Components</th>
                <th>SWC</th>
                <th>SWCM</th>
                <th>Technology</th>
                <th>Design Diagram</th>
                <th>Gitlab Url</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {results.map((result, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{result.tier}</td>
                  <td>{result.designPattern}</td>
                  <td>{result.component}</td>
                  <td>{result.swc}</td>
                  <td>{result.swcm}</td>
                  <td>{result.technology}</td>
                  <td>{result.designDiagram}</td>
                  <td>{result.gitlabUrl}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        ) : (
          <p>No results found</p>
        )}
      </div>

